# variable loses value outside while loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, while-loop, linked-list

I'm trying to solve this problem involving linkedlists. Partition a linked list so that values less than the partition come first followed by values equal to or greater than the partition.

Example:

```
input: 90 -> 30 -> 40 -> 50 -> 100 -> 40
partition: 50
output: 30 -> 40 -> 40 -> 50 -> 100 -> 90
```

Everything less than the partition(50) comes before all nodes greater than the partition(50).

```js
function partitionLl(node) {
  let list = {
    "head": {
      "data": 90,
      "next": {
        "data": 30,
        "next": {
          "data": 40,
          "next": {
            "data": 50,
            "next": {
              "data": 100,
              "next": {
                "data": 40,
                "next": {
                  "data": 15,
                  "next": {
                    "data": 90,
                    "next": {
                      "data": 200,
                      "next": {
                        "data": 90,
                        "next": {
                          "data": 10,
                          "next": {
                            "data": 90,
                            "next": null
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  let test;
  let current = list.head;
  let p1 = {
    data: null,
    next: null
  };
  let p2 = current;

  while (current !== null) {
    if (current.data < node) {
      p1 = current;
      p1 = p1.next;
    } else {
      p2 = current;
      p2 = p2.next;
    }

    current = current.next;
  }
  console.log(p1)
  console.log(p2)

}

partitionLl(50)
```

This is the code I have and the list I am aiming to get is great while in the loop, it has the list that I need. The problem is that I need to attach these lists(p1 and p2) when the loop is completed, but the variables log something completely different and inaccurate when outside the while loop.

The current variable is being tracked both in side and outside the loop. Not sure why this is or what kind of scope loop might have that causes this. How would I access the values out side the loop?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. where should the last node go? do you want to get a tree instead of a linked list?

Comment: Yes, just edited the comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "log something completely different?" Can you show us what you get?

Comment: why comes the first grreter value to the end of the list? why not maintain the order?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the OPs program is that it never actually changes the list and also does not build a new list for the result, i.e. no assignment to a data or next property ever happens. Only the "pointers" p1 and p2 are moved around, until the end of the list is reached. The way the assignments are done, either p1, or p2 are bound to be null in the end.

A solution would create copies of the current element and append them to either p1 or p2 by setting the next property.

Like so:

```
function partitionLl(node) {
  let list = {
    "head": {
      "data": 90,
      "next": {
        "data": 30,
        "next": {
          "data": 40,
          "next": {
            "data": 50,
            "next": {
              "data": 100,
              "next": {
                "data": 40,
                "next": {
                  "data": 15,
                  "next": {
                    "data": 90,
                    "next": {
                      "data": 200,
                      "next": {
                        "data": 90,
                        "next": {
                          "data": 10,
                          "next": {
                            "data": 90,
                            "next": null
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

    let p1 = {
        "head": null
    }
    let t1 = p1.head
    let p2 = {
        "head": null
    }
    let t2 = p2.head
    let current = list.head
    while (current !== null) {
      if (current.data < node) {

          if(p1.head === null) {
              p1.head = {
                  "data": current.data,
                  "next": null
              }
              t1 = p1.head
          } else {
              t1.next = {
                  "data": current.data,
                  "next": null
              }
              t1 = t1.next
          }
    } else {
          if(p2.head === null) {
              p2.head = {
                  "data": current.data,
                  "next": null
              }
              t2 = p2.head
          } else {
              t2.next = {
                  "data": current.data,
                  "next": null
              }
              t2 = t2.next
          }
    }

    current = current.next;
  }
  console.log(p1)
  console.log(p2)

}

partitionLl(50)
```

Comment: I think the solutions in the other answers are neater, I just tried to stay consistent with the OP's style too make the difference apparent ...

Comment: You're right, I would need to chain on those values but instead I was just replacing p1 over and over again. Ok, I'll try that method - so `p1.next = current`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Typically working with linked lists are exercises in using recursion.

I'd build a couple of primitives for working with linked lists and then combine them to produce the result that you want - `partition` can be built from a `filter` and `concat`:

`// given a list return a new list that contains only those items than pass the test function
const filter = (list, test) => {
  const next = list.next ? filter(list.next, test) : null;
  if (test(list.data)) {
    return { data: list.data, next };
  }
  return next;
};`

`// given two lists return a new list with them concatenated together
const concat = (l1, l2) => {
  if (!l1.next) {
    return { data: l1.data, next: l2 };
  }
  return { data: l1.data, next: concat(l1.next, l2) };
};`

`const partition = (list, value) => {
  const smaller = filter(list, d => d < value);
  const bigger = filter(list, d => d >= value);
  return concat(smaller, bigger);
};`

Answer (score 0):

You could take three lists for smaller values: (a) `left`; (b) for greater or equal values `right`; and (c) split the `right` part into `first` and `last`, where all values goes into the `last` list until the pivot value is found, and then all values goes into `first`.

At the end, combine all lists to a single one, and return a new list.

```js
function partition(list, pivot) {
    var leftHead = {},
        left = leftHead,
        firstHead = {},
        lastHead = {},
        right = lastHead,
        isLast = true,
        node = list.head;

    while (node) {
        if (node.data === pivot && isLast) {
            right = firstHead;
            isLast = false;
        }

        if (node.data < pivot) {
            left.next = { data: node.data };
            left = left.next;
        } else {
            right.next = { data: node.data };
            right = right.next;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }

    if (firstHead.next) {
        right.next = lastHead.next;
        left.next = firstHead.next;
    } else {
        left.next = lastHead.next;
    }
    return { head: leftHead.next };

}

var list1 = { head: { data: 90, next: { data: 30, next: { data: 40, next: { data: 50, next: { data: 100, next: { data: 40, next: { data: 15, next: { data: 90, next: { data: 200, next: { data: 90, next: { data: 10, next: { data: 90, next: null } } } } } } } } } } } } },
    list2 = { head: { data: 90, next: { data: 30, next: { data: 40, next: { data: 50, next: { data: 100, next: { data: 40 } } } } } } };

console.log(partition(list1, 50));
console.log(partition(list2, 50));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like this breakdown and would like to understand it better. For this line `left.next = { data: node.data };` how is next being called when `var left ` is initially set to an empty object with no properties? Is this a weird Javascript thing where, the property not defined is equivalent to null but you can still call it?

Comment: `isLast` should this be called `isFirst`? or what's the meaning of this variable?

Comment: ad 2: `isLast` is a flag, which right side is taken. so `last` get filled before `first`, to maintain the order of the list. ad 1: `left` is an object. `left.next` is a property of `left` with an asigned value (an object).